# One line if statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I'd like to to some thing similar to JavaScript's

```
var foo = true;
foo && doSometing();
```

but this doesn't seem to work in PHP.

I'm trying to add a class to a label if a condition is met and I'd prefer to keep the embedded PHP down to a minimum for the sake of readability.

So far I've got:

```
<?php $redText='redtext ';?>
<label class="<?php if ($requestVars->_name=='')echo $redText;?>labellong">_name*</label>
<input name="_name" value="<?php echo $requestVars->_name; ?>"/>
```

but even then the IDE is complaining that I have an if statement without braces.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

use the ternary operator ?:

change this

```
<?php if ($requestVars->_name == '') echo $redText; ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo ($requestVars->_name == '') ? $redText : ''; ?>
```

In short

```
// (Condition)?(thing's to do if condition true):(thing's to do if condition false);
```

Comment: I did think of using a ternary if, but dismissed it as i didn't have an else condition. using `''` as the else is a good idea.

Comment: isn't this counter intuitive to have the `echo` on the left (condition) side and not in the command?

Answer (score 33):

You can use **Ternary operator logic**
Ternary operator logic is the process of using "(condition)? (true return value) : (false return value)" statements to shorten your if/else structures. i.e

```
/* most basic usage */
$var = 5;
$var_is_greater_than_two = ($var > 2 ? true : false); // returns true
```

Comment: +1 for the name of the operator, as it helps who doens't know how to call it (like myself) for future references...

Answer (score 13):

Something like this?

```
($var > 2 ? echo "greater" : echo "smaller")
```

Comment: why duplicate echo 2 times?

Answer (score 7):

**Sample Usage**

Here are a couple more uses of ternary operators, ranging from simple to advanced:

**Basic Usage:**

```
$message = 'Hello '.($user->is_logged_in() ? $user->get('first_name') : 'Guest');
```

**Short hand Usage:**

```
$message = 'Hello '.($user->get('first_name') ?: 'Guest');
```

**Echo Inline**

```
echo 'Based on your score, you are a ',($score > 10 ? 'genius' : 'nobody');
```

**A bit Tougher**

```
$score = 10;
$age = 20;
echo 'Taking into account your age and score, you are: ',($age > 10 ? ($score < 80 ? 'behind' : 'above average') : ($score < 50 ? 'behind' : 'above average')); // returns 'You are behind'
```

**complicated level**

```
 $days = ($month == 2 ? ($year % 4 ? 28 : ($year % 100 ? 29 : ($year %400 ? 28 : 29))) : (($month - 1) % 7 % 2 ? 30 : 31)); //returns days in the given month
```

To learn more about ternary operators and usage, visit PHP.net [Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) or [here](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators).

Answer (score 5):

I like to use the minimalist PHP text output syntax:

```
HTML stuff <?= $some_string ?> HTML stuff
```

(This works the same as using an `<?php echo $some_string; ?>`)

You can also use the ternary operator:

```
//(condition) ? (do_something_when_true) : (do_something_when_false);
($my_var == true) ? "It's true" : "It's false ;
```

Ending up like this:

```
<?= ($requestVars->_name=='') ? $redText : '' ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use ternary operator:

```
echo (($test == '') ? $redText : '');
echo $test == '' ? $redText : ''; //removed parenthesis
```

But in this case you can't use shorter reversed version because it will return `bool(true)` in first condition.

```
echo (($test != '') ?: $redText); //this will not work properly for this case
```

Answer (score 0):

Ill provide with an other answer since the original question specifies the use of if() in html

```
<a class="menu-item" href="/about-us"><?= (pll_current_language() == 'en') ? 'About us' : 'Om oss' ?></a>
```

Answer (score -11):

The provided answers are the best solution in your case, and they are what I do as well, but if your text is printed by a function or class method you could do the same as in Javascript as well

```
function hello(){
echo 'HELLO';
}
$print = true;
$print && hello();
```