# Adding variables in PHP array and identifying and swapping variables

Tags: php

New here and completely out of my comfort zone in my current PHP course. I need help with two different things in an assignment I'm working on. The first is how to make yes appear instead of 4k or blueray in the appropriate columns in the following code:

```
    <?php
$items = array(
     array("title" => "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 19.99),
     array("title" => "Wonder Woman 2017", 'type' => "4K","price" => 24.99),
     array("title" => "Spider-Man: Homecoming", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 22.99),
     array("title" => "War For The Planet Of The Apes", 'type' => "4K","price" => 19.99),
     array("title" => "Baby Driver", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 24.99),
     array("title" => "Atomic Blonde", 'type' => "4K","price" => 24.99),
     array("title" => "Moana", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 15.99),
     array("title" => "Alien: Covenant", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 21.96),
     array("title" => "Despicable Me 3", 'type' => "4K","price" => 24.99),
     array("title" => "Firefly Complete Series", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 20.99),
);
//sorting titles alphabetically
sort($items);
?>

    <?php //creating forloop and assigning array items string values. Then looping through the title, type, and price elements to display them within the correct table rows and columns.
 foreach ($items as $key => $value){
echo "<tr><td>".$value["title"]."</td><td>".$value['type']."</td><td>".$value['type']."</td><td>$".$value["price"]."</td></tr>";     }
?>
```

The other issue I'm having trouble figuring out is how to access and add all of the inventory values I have created in this code by multiplying $value[price] and $value [quantity] in my foreach loop:

```
    <?php
$items = array(
     array("title" => "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 19.99,"qty" => 25),
     array("title" => "Wonder Woman 2017", 'type' => "4K","price" => 24.99,"qty" => 32),
     array("title" => "Spider-Man: Homecoming", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 22.99,"qty" => 17),
     array("title" => "War For The Planet Of The Apes", 'type' => "4K","price" => 19.99,"qty" => 2),
     array("title" => "Baby Driver", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 24.99,"qty" => 25),
     array("title" => "Atomic Blonde", 'type' => "4K","price" => 24.99,"qty" => 11),
     array("title" => "Moana", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 15.99,"qty" => 21),
     array("title" => "Alien: Covenant", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 21.96,"qty" => 19),
     array("title" => "Despicable Me 3", 'type' => "4K","price" => 24.99,"qty" => 33),
     array("title" => "Firefly Complete Series", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 20.99,"qty" => 15),
);
rsort($items);
?>

  <?php //creating forloop and assigning array items string values. Then looping through the title, type, and price elements to display them within the correct table rows and columns.
                //added qty column and created inventory column by multiplying qty and price values.
 foreach ($items as $key => $value){
echo "<tr><td>".$value["title"]."</td><td>".$value['type']."</td><td>".$value['type']."</td><td>".$value["price"]."</td><td>".$value['qty']."</td><td>$".$value["price"]*$value['qty']."</td></tr>";     }
?>
```

Thank you in advanced to anyone willing to help!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write `array()` every time, you can just do it like this:

```
$var = [
       ["title" => "Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2", 'type' => "blue-ray","price" => 19.99]
];
```

Then for your loop and checking if something is 4k you can do this:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $value){
    echo "<tr><td>".$value["title"]."</td><td>".(($value['type'] == '4k')? 'Yes' : $value['type'])."</td><td>$".$value["price"]."</td></tr>";
}
```

More information about that here:
[one line if statement in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078149/one-line-if-statement-in-php)

Or here:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 0):

What are your table headings? Is your expected output like this:

| Title | Blue Ray | 4K | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Guardians of the Galaxy | Yes | - | $19.99 |
| Wonder Woman | - | Yes | $24.99 |

If so you can use an if statement or ternary operator to demine the type value, then, if true set a variable to "Yes" and use that in your table.

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>BlueRay</th>
<th>4K</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>

<?php //creating forloop and assigning array items string values. Then looping through the title, type, and price elements to display them within the correct table rows and columns.
    foreach ($items as $key => $value){


    $type4k = $value['type'] == "4K" ? "yes": " - ";
    $typeBluRay = $value['type'] == "blue-ray" ? "yes": " - ";

    echo "<tr><td>".$value["title"]."</td><td>".$typeBluRay."</td><td>".$type4k."</td><td>$".$value["price"]."</td></tr>";     }

?>


</table>
```

For your second question, you can create a variable called $totalInventory to store the inventory total. Each time your forloop is run it will add the inventory cost to the total cost. You can read up more about how forloops work [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$totalInventory = 0;

foreach ($items as $key => $value){
 
$inventory = $value["price"]*$value['qty'];
 
echo "<tr><td>".$value["title"]."</td><td>".$value['type']."</td> 
<td>".$value['type']."</td><td>".$value["price"]."</td><td>".$value['qty']." 
</td><td>$".$inventory."</td></tr>";    

  $totalInventory = $totalInventory+$inventory;
}
```